# Bootstrap-sass Gem v.s. CDN

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

Various Ruby on Rails tutorials encourage the instillation of the bootstrap-sass gem. Why is this a convention rather than point to a CDN?

I've included in header of my app:

```
  <!-- BOOTSTRAP CSS 3.3.5 CDN: --> <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And in the footer:

```
  <!-- BOOTSTRAP JS 3.3.5 CDN --><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Assuming I am always working from a development box that is connected to the internet: What is the reasoning behind using the bootstrap gem rather than just pointing to a CDN?  Isn't it always faster to point to a CDN where a client is likely to have the file already cached?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The likely reason that Rails' tutorials suggest the `bootstrap-sass` gem is just a matter of convenience; as Rails' developers we're used to adding a line to our Gemfile to integrate 3rd party libraries.

There are added benefits to the gem: after you do a `bundle install` you won't need an internet connection to load your development environment's assets (no need to connect to an external CDN).  Also you can use `SASS` to override Bootstrap mixin variables and customize the framework.

These benefits aside, if you aren't customizing Bootstrap there is no need to use the `boostrap-sass` gem in production.  In fact your argument about clients possibly already having CDN hosted versions of common JS/CSS frameworks is certainly valid.

Short answer: don't think of the `boostrap-sass` gem as a convention.  It's a good starting point for customization but if no customization is needed it is perfectly reasonable to go with a CDN.

Comment: Assuming the versions are the same, would it be reasonable to include the bootstrap gem in the "group :development" in order to allow for local development without internet?

Comment: In general, I would expect any customization to Bootstrap to happen in a separate CSS file (so your not modifying the original Bootstrap files directly). I'm having a hard time seeing a reason why you would ever run the bootstrap-sass gem in production.

Comment: You could do that but you'll have to make modifications to your view layouts and/or asset manifest files to conditionally reference  the cdn or local variant of Bootstrap depending on Rails.env.

Comment: I don't agree it being in the tutorials is mainly convenience. The whole point of using bootstrap-sass is that it neatly integrates with the sass pipeline, and you can take full advantage of bootstrap being sass code. 
As for me, putting bootstrap specific classes in your html is a big no-go; I consider it way better to put semantic classes in your html, and make link the bootstrap-specific stuff in the app's scss/sass files using appropriate techniques like import, extend, ... 

This also make your application less tied to (a specific version of) a CSS framework...

Comment: Also, if you are also having some css/less/sass that is additional for your app, you will be downloading multiple css files if you're using a CDN for bootstrap, while Rails by convention wraps everything in one application.css. Given the fact that Rails is still HTTP1.1, you might even loose speed by using the CDN...

Comment: Counter-points to your argument on performance: if a user's browser has already cached the cdn-served bootstrap package from one of the thousands of sites also linking to it, the library won't need to be pulled down at all.  HTTP/2 support in Rails is under development still but that point shouldn't matter either because your webserver should be serving static assets in production, not Rails.

Answer (score -1):

Using the CDN merely gives you CSS, hard-wiring your HTML files to a specific bootstrap version. Using the SASS/LESS version of bootstrap on the contrary allows you to put semantic classes on your HTML, and make the connection between your semantic classes and Bootstrap in your app specific SASS/LESS files (using `@import`, `@extend` ... statements)

If you use this technique wisely, you will end up with smaller sized downloads since you only import the parts of bootstrap you actually use in your application, and you will have clean separation of concerns, allowing you to switch sass/less frameworks without touching your HTML files (ideally).